# Locate text inside a html tag with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get the price(234,40 €) from the below HTML with selenium.

```html
<a class="js-sku-link sku-link" title="Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm Αδιάβροχο με Παλμογράφο (Black)" data-e2e-testid="sku-price-link" href="/s/30445632/Samsung-Galaxy-Watch4-Classic-Bluetooth-Stainless-Steel-46mm-%CE%91%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%AC%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%87%CE%BF-%CE%BC%CE%B5-%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%86%CE%BF-Black.html"><span>από</span>234,39 €</a>
```

I have tried:

```
min_price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'js-sku-link').get_attribute('text')


min_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "από")]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Can you share the results you are getting in order to see what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
min_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm Αδιάβροχο με Παλμογράφο (Black)']").text
```

Or

```py
min_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@title,'Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm')]").text
```

In case you need to add a wait to make element be visible you may use something like this:

```py
min_price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm Αδιάβροχο με Παλμογράφο (Black)']"))).text
```

Or

```py
min_price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contain(@title,'Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm)]"))).text
```

respectively
**UPD**
The `//a[@title='Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm Αδιάβροχο με Παλμογράφο (Black)']` locator matches 3 elements inside the same product block. To access the price element you need to precise your locator.
This will give you the price of the product you are looking for:
min_price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Samsung Galaxy Watch4 Classic Bluetooth Stainless Steel 46mm Αδιάβροχο με Παλμογράφο (Black)' and @data-e2e-testid='sku-price-link']"))).text
To get all the products on that page prices you can use something like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-e2e-testid='sku-price-link']")))
time.sleep(0.5)
prices = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-e2e-testid='sku-price-link']")
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Prophet for your answer but it prints nothing

Comment: Well, we need a link to see the actual elements and give a correct locators

Comment: I want to track prices from https://www.skroutz.gr/c/1705/Smartwatches/m/28/Samsung.html?keyphrase=watch+4

Comment: OK, see my updated answer and please let me know if now it resolved your issue

Comment: It works. With latest code i can take the price from first element. Thank you!